# Invalid Liscense exception while calling a secured url via Apache Axis

Tags: java, httpclient, security, ssl-certificate, axis

Hi I am getting the following invalid liscence exception while calling a secured URL lets say "https://adcenter.microsoft.com/"  from Apache Axis, i think this must also be the case with HTTPClient as well, i know we can generate a .keysotre  with java tool and put that in server's conf directory works but in this scenario i am invoking the code via main Method so .keystore kept in servers conf wont help , please suggest how to install a cerificate/Liscense for a secured url in java so that we run the code either under webserver environment  or just by calling main method this should work

```
  Exception in thread "main" com.dstc.security.util.licensing.InvalidLicense: Cannot load license for module jcsi.provider
at com.dstc.security.util.licensing.LicenseValidator.loadLicense(LicenseValidator.java:87)
at com.dstc.security.util.licensing.LicenseValidator.check(LicenseValidator.java:290)
at com.dstc.security.provider.symm.Licensed.<clinit>(Licensed.java:60)
at com.dstc.security.provider.symm.BlockCipher.<clinit>(BlockCipher.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:82)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:113)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:361)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:399)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:378)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:145)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.buildAvailableCache(CipherSuiteList.java:215)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.getDefault(CipherSuiteList.java:239)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:520)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:358)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:71)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:92)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular issue seems unrelated to Axis or HttpClient: the JRE is using an SSL provider which expects a valid license (i.e. you need to pay to use it). Did you intend to use the ["Wedgetail JCSI components"](http://web.archive.org/web/20041204155625/http://www.wedgetail.com/jcsi/provider/index.html) as SSL provider for any particular reason (an old version of Java perhaps)?

If not, check your classpath. Maybe someone has added that JCSI JAR to it (it has a name like "jcsi_base.jar") and forgot about it, or they forgot to include the "jcsi_license.jar" file.